# Show particular record from database in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I need to show last saved record in crystal report.

I know I can do it with `recordSelectionFormula` , I tried too,
on report Preview form load event

```
if (ReportName == "Bill Receipt")
{
    Report.RecordSelectionFormula = String.Format("{0} == (BillNo) AND {0} == (BillNO) ","{BILLH.Bh_no}" , BillNo);
}
```

`BillNo` is the variable gets value from property set on the form,its value is passed from another `Billform`

```
public int BillNo { get; set; }
```

but it showing exception

A number currency amount boolean date time or string is expected here
Please tell me if anything wrong with my code.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are going wrong in code ,try this

```
if (ReportName == "Bill Receipt")
            {
                Report.RecordSelectionFormula = String.Format("{0} = {1} AND {2}={3} ", "{BILLH.Bh_no}", BillNo, "{BILL.B_no}", BillNo);

            }
```